# html input file action after file selected

Tags: html, file, input, action

I am in a predicament with input files. The project I am working on has added a jQuery extension that masks all input types and makes them more 'vibrant'. However it has also caused a lot of trouble in the updating of what is listed in these inputs. One such problem is the input with type file. It currently will not change what is being uploaded after the very first selection. So I am wondering if there is a command you can use to do something after the user has selected a file (pressed the Open) button.

Comment: A command, like "fix this with magic"? What are you asking for?

Comment: I really just wanted to know how to do an action, pretty much binding however the post below where you do it on change doesn't work for some reason. I believe the problem may be in the jQuery that is masking all of my input types. What I am attempting to do is what t3hb4tman had interpreted. I want an action after the user has selected a specific file.

Comment: Hace it mask only the ones with a class name that you supply. It will then leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly positive on what you're asking for but: you can bind logic to the input's `onchange` event. This will run the code attached to it after the user has selected their file(s) and pressed the "Open" or "Cancel" buttons.

Here's an example using jQuery (since you've already stated you're using it):

```
$("#yourFileInput").change( function() {
  alert("Hey, you changed me!");
});
```